# Скрывать input если пустой

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Подскажите как скрывать input если он пустой.

```
<input class="form-check-inline" type="radio" name="question" value="'.$scripts['scripts_url13'].'"/>
'.$scripts['scripts_answer13'].'<br />';
```

Пробовал:

```
if($('.form-check-inline').text() == ' '){
  $('.form-check-inline').css({'display': 'none'});
} else {
  $('.form-check-inline').css({'display': 'form-check-inline'});
}
```

Но результата не дало

Comment: Угу... а как в него юзер будет что-то вводить, в скрытый-то?

Comment: у вас  сравнивается не с пустой строкой а с пробелом

Comment: и лучше вместо text() == "" писать text().length == 0

Comment: В том то и дело что юзер не должен видеть этот инпут (.$scripts['scripts_answer13'].)  если он приходит пустой

Comment: А зачем вы его пытаетесь на js скрыть вообще? ставьте в `php` `style="display:none"` если нет значения, на js это будет прыгать тк изначально инпут будет присутствовать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понял, нужно скрыть `input`,если в него не передано значение.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.form-check-inline').each(function(){
    if(this.value == '' || this.value == undefined){
      $(this).hide();
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="form-check-inline" type="radio" name="question" value="'.$scripts['scripts_url13'].'"/>

<input class="form-check-inline" type="radio" name="question" value=""/>
```

Comment: Спасибо!То что нужно!

Answer (score 1):

А нужен ли вам Javascript (и AJAX) вообще? Скрыть элемент с пустым атрибутом можно и силами CSS2, поддерживаемым всеми браузерами без исключения:

```css
input[value=''] {display: none}
```

```html
<input class="form-check-inline" type="radio" name="question" value="'.$scripts['scripts_url13'].'"/>
<input class="form-check-inline" type="radio" name="question" value=""/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Я так понял какой-то вопросник. Не знаю зачем скрывать, но вижу как минимум, что

```
$('.form-check-inline').css({'display': 'form-check-inline'});
```

В css нет display:form-check-inline. Поменяй хотя бы на display:block(inline-block). И поставь как тебе выше писали `text().length == 0`

Comment: Текст для инпутов в примере находится вне проверяемого элемента, такая проверка работать не будет

Answer (score -1):

Я бы лучше обернул радио кнопки в лейблы и проверял текст уже в лейблах

```js
$('.radio-label').each(function() {
  if (!$(this).text().length) $(this).hide();
  else $(this).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="radio-label"><input type="radio" name="question" value="lul"></label>
<label class="radio-label"><input type="radio" name="question" value="lulz">choose me!</label>
```